# auto start or enable service on boot up permanently ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: startup

how to auto start or enable service on next boot up or start up? in ubuntu 16.04 lts
how to start or enable service on the next boot up or start up? in ubuntu 16.04 lts

without doing it manually enable or start services again everytime i start up or boot up the ubuntu 16.04 lts

thank you

Answer (score 37):

It sounds like you're looking for:

```
systemctl enable example-service.service
```

It doesn't sound like you have whatever service it is permanently disabled, but if it was, you would do:

```
systemctl unmask example-service.service
```

as well to re-enable being able to start the service.

Comment: systemctl came with ubuntu18.04
ubuntu 16.04 has got init.d, it uses 

    service servicename start|status|stop